# android SQLite DataBase query 1

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to make a simple Android game(like Quiz) where by `SQLiteDatabase` there would be saved  the results of the players(results and names). But using this code it gives an Error.

Please help me to understand what I am doing wrong. Thank you in Advance :).

```
public class forth extends Activity {
DBHelper dbHelper;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.forth); 

    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
TextView tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
TextView tvResults = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResults);
Intent intent = getIntent();
String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    String points = intent.getIntExtra("balance", 0);

  ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
  SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

  cv.put("points", points);
  cv.put("name", name);
  db.insert("mytable", null, cv);
  Cursor c = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, null);
  int PointsColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("points"); 
  int nameColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name");  

   tvResults.setText(c.getString(nameColIndex) + " " +c.getInt(PointsColIndex));
} 

  class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DBHelper(Context context) {
          super(context, "myDB", null, 1);
        }


        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


          db.execSQL("create table mytable ("
              + "balance integer primary key autoincrement," 
              + "name text,"
              + "surname text" + ");");
        }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
      }   
     }
```

Comment: Knowing the error would be useful, that way people are more influenced to help you, especially if the error is something people are familiar with.  If it has a line number, denote which line corresponds to that line number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tren, the problem is we cant see where there error is... could you load LogCat? 
but try getting the info from the intent like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        language = bundle.getString("Language");
```

also in query try to use `db.query(dbHelper.YOUR_TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);`

fill in the on upgrade...
let me send you a link to a great SQLITE tutorial...follow it... its worth it

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

try it and also :

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

I think you'll find your answers and a better way to build your SQL table

Comment: No worries... As long as I helped:)

Comment: But the problem isn't in Intent, the problem is with SQLite. The problem is in either reading or adding data. Although I think that it is connected more with reading.

Comment: did you review the tutorials? they pretty much cover everything... and like i said its linda difficult giving you a straight answer when I cant see the exact problem... I would recommend you follow the tutorials and build your SQL DB as instructed...It really does cover everything

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a `Bundle object` to retrieve data coming along with `intent`. I think you should do that.

Comment: I am sorry I am just a beginner. Would you please give me an example in my code, of course if it is not difficult, thank you. :)

Comment: Intent intent = getIntent(); Bundle bun=intent.getExtras(); String str=bun.getString("name"); Try to run this.

Comment: But the problem isn't in Intent, the problem is with SQLite. The problem is in either reading or adding data. Although I think that it is connected more with reading DB.

Comment: @TrenNarek Why choose an accepted answer then if you haven't solved your problem?  I also don't know what error you're getting.